# Product of all real solutions of equation $\frac {2013x}{2014}=2013^{\log_x2014}$?

Tags: logarithms

How am I even supposed to start this task, i need some hint? I logarithm both sides and these are my steps:
$$\frac{2013x}{2014}=2013^{\log_x2014}$$
$$\log_{2013}\frac{2013x}{2014}=\log_{2013}2013^{\log_x2014}$$
$$\log_{2013}\frac{2013x}{2014}=\log_x2014$$
$$\log_{2013}{2013} + \log_{2013}{x} - \log_{2013}{2014} = \log_{x}{2014}$$
$$1 + \log_{2013}{x} - \log_{2013}{2014} = \log_{x}{2014}$$
After this step I do not know what to do next.

Comment: I'd use the base-change property of logarithms:$$\log_x a=\frac{\log_ya}{\log_yx},\quad a>0,(x,y)\neq 1\wedge (x,y)>0$$then you should come up with a second order linear equation by substituting $z=\log_{2013}x$

Answer (score 0):

From your third last step:

$$\log_{2013}\frac{2013x}{2014}=\log_x2014$$
$$\frac{\log2013+\log x-\log2014}{\log2013}=\frac{\log2014}{\log x}$$
$$(\log x)^2+(\log2013-\log2014)\log x-\log2013\log2014=0$$
$$(\log x +\log2013)(\log x-\log2014)=0$$

$$\log x=\log2014 \text{ or } -\log2013$$

$$x=2014 \text{ or } \frac1 {2013}$$

So product of solutions $=\frac{2014}{2013}$

Comment: Why $\log x+\log2013=0$ is rejected? $x=1/2013$ should be a solution since the function $\log x$ can be negative

Comment: oh yes. I shall add it back to solution.Thx

Comment: No problem ;) It's also interesting to notice that $x_1/x_2=1+1/x_2$

Answer (score 0):

It's simpler to start by taking the logarithm to the base $2014$. Then you get $$a+y-1=\frac ay,$$where $a=\log_{2014}2013$ and $y=\log_{2014}x.$ This is a quadratic equation, the sum of whose roots will give you the product of the roots (in $x$) of the original equation.